# Как пишется "цинкжелезосодержащий"?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

Подскажите, пожалуйста (желательно со ссылкой на правило), как пишется "цинкжелезосодержащий"?

Answer (score 1):

Это же термин, так можно нанизывать неограниченное число корней.

[**...содержащий**](http://www.efremova.info/letter/+s.html?page=2)

Конечная часть сложных прилагательных, вносящая значение: заключающий в себе то, что указано в первой части слова (золотосодержащий, платиносодержащий, калийсодержащий и т.п.).

---

[**цинксодержащий**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9) (и цинкосодержащий), [**железосодержащий**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9);

термины *цинкжелезосодержащий,* *цинксвинецоловосодержащий* встретились мне только в специальной литературе, источник заслуживает уважения:

[Вестник Челябинского государственного университета.
2015. № 18 (373). Экономика. Вып. 51. С. 80–89.](http://www.lib.csu.ru/vch/373/009.pdf)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P. S. Обратила внимание на Ваши теги, - уау, какой дефис?! Только слитно, а проблемный момент в подобных словах - исключительно соединительная гласная (при выборе между *цинксодержащий* и *цинк**о**содержащий* я за первый вариант).

Comment: Галина, мне встречались и через дефис.Источник тоже заслуженный.

Comment: Галина, если бы не встречала через дефис, не поставила бы такой тег. И таким ссылок довольно много. А у Вестника Челябинского университета своя редакция, которая тоже может сделать ошибку.

Comment: Если Вы говорите о дефисе между двумя металлами - "цинк-железосодержащий" (слитное написание с *содержащий* сомнений не вызывает), то - да: и правила нет, и словарями не фиксируется. Мне, редактору, такой дефис дик. Это как поселить дефис(ы) в кинофоторадиоаппаратуре.